# Where I can ask for a review and feedback on my application?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am personally developing a web application. I was looking for a Stack Exchange site where I can ask other developers to look into that and give some feedback/suggestions. I know the Stack Exchange network is primarily for questions/answers, but I was wondering if it has such discussion/forum like area for such purpose may be?

If Stack Exchange doesn't have such facility, it would be good if you can give some other suggested sites where I can get such feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "if it has such discussion/forum" SE has worked hard to ensure sites *don't* turn into this.  A strong effort is make to ensure new sites *don't* do this, and to kill any sites that devolve into that.  So no, there are no sites just for discussions/forums.  There are a million other forums/discussion sites out there, SE exists to explicitly offer an alternative.

Comment: @Servy well, except for meta and the [meta-tag:discussion] tag.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII True.

Comment: You might want to try http://discourse.org (made by some of the same guys who made SE).

Answer (score 4):

If you want feedback regarding a *specific working piece of code* of your existing application, [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the right place. From the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects
>    you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific working piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!

However, if you are primarily looking for discussion or for input related to broader goals or high-level architecture, there isn't a StackExchange site that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> I was looking for a stackoverflow child site where I can ask other developers to look into that and give some feedbacks/suggestions.

It does not exist. Not on Stack Exchange.

> I know stackoverflow network is primarily for question/answers

Yes but don't forget that  **All** Stack Exchange sites are like this. Stack Overflow is just one of them.

So to answer you question unfortunatly no Stack Exchange sites will accept these kind of questions.

Comment: "It does not exist. Not on Stack Exchange." [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Yannis Touché...

Comment: @yannis: codereview probably isn't really well-suited for the review of an entire web application.